# How to interpret a number as the power of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I know that $\{0,1\}^2$ gives $(1,1)^T,(1,0)^T,(0,1)^T,(0,1)^T$.

1. What would be the result for $\{0,1\}^4$?
2. Is there any function in Python that gives $\{0,1\}^n$ where n is a positive natural number?

Comment: `itertools.product`. But programming questions should be asked at `stackoverflow.com`, not `math.stackexchange.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1, the result are $4-$tuples with entries $0$ and $1$ in all combinations.  There are $16$ of them.  You can use the transpose to make column vectors if you want.  For 2, I am sure there is.